# How do a assign a GUID to a DAO parameter in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, guid

I have a piece of code that boils down to

```
dim stmt   as dao.queryDef
dim parId  as dao.parameter

set stmt = currentDB().createQueryDef("", _
    "parameters id guid, ...; insert into tab (id, ... ) values ([id], ...)")
```

I created the table with

```
 create table tab (
    id guid,
    ...
 )
```

and

```
alter table tab add constraint tab_pk primary key (id)
```

Later, I want to assign a GUID to `parId`:

```
parId.value = GuidFromString("{936DA01F-9ABD-4D9D-80C7-02AF85C822A8}")
```

This assignment causes a *Run-time error 3421*: `Data type conversion error`.

How is it possible to assign a GUID to a `dao.parameter` variable?

### Updated example

This is an updated example that uses a `longbinary` parameter that is not working in my environment: it causes a *Runtime Error 3001 (Invalid Argument)* when `stmt.execute` is executed.

```
option explicit

sub main() ' {

    dim db as dao.database
    set db = application.currentDB

  ' db.execute("drop table tab")

    createTable  db
    insertValues db

end sub ' }

sub createTable(db as dao.database) ' {

    db.execute(   _
   "create table tab ( " & _
   "  id     guid,     " & _
   "  txt    char(60)  " & _
   ")")

   db.execute("alter table tab add constraint tab_pk primary key (id)")


end sub ' }


sub insertValues(db as dao.database) ' {

     dim stmt as dao.queryDef

     set stmt = db.createQueryDef("",   _
       "parameters "                  & _
       "  id     longbinary,  "       & _
       "  txt    char(60);    "       & _
       "insert into tab values ([id], [txt]) ")


     dim parId   as dao.parameter
     dim parTxt  as dao.parameter

     set parId  = stmt.parameters("id" )
     set parTxt = stmt.parameters("txt")

     parId.value  =  GuidFromString("{936DA01F-9ABD-4D9D-80C7-02AF85C822A8}")
     parTxt.value = "Hello world."

     stmt.execute ' Access throws Runtime Error 3001 (Invalid argument)

end sub ' }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GUID type is a special type that's not valid as a parameter.

Instead, use `LONGBINARY` to pass the GUID as binary data to the query:

```
set stmt = currentDB().createQueryDef("", _
    "parameters id LONGBINARY, ...; insert into tab (id, ... ) values ([id], ...)")
```

---

In response to the new MCVE:

The main error there is the `VARCHAR` declaration. The following modifications work:

```
Sub insertValues(db As dao.Database) ' {
     Dim stmt As dao.QueryDef
     Set stmt = db.CreateQueryDef("", _
       "parameters " & _
       "  idparam   LONGBINARY ;" & _
       "insert into tab(ID)  values ([idparam]) ")
     Dim parId   As dao.Parameter
     Dim parTxt  As dao.Parameter

     Set parId = stmt.Parameters("idparam")
     'Set parTxt = stmt.Parameters("txtparam")
     stmt.Parameters!idparam.Value = GUIDFromString("{936DA01F-9ABD-4D9D-80C7-02AF85C822A8}")
     'stmt.Parameters!txtparam.Value = "Hello world."
     stmt.Execute 'no errors
End Sub ' }
```

And

```
Sub insertValues(db As dao.Database) ' {
     Dim stmt As dao.QueryDef
     Set stmt = db.CreateQueryDef("", _
       "parameters " & _
       "  idparam   BINARY, txtparam CHAR(60) ;" & _
       "insert into tab  values ([idparam], txtparam) ")
     Dim parId   As dao.Parameter
     Dim parTxt  As dao.Parameter

     Set parId = stmt.Parameters("idparam")
     Set parTxt = stmt.Parameters("txtparam")
     stmt.Parameters!idparam.Value = GUIDFromString("{936DA01F-9ABD-4D9D-80C7-02AF85C822A8}")
     stmt.Parameters!txtparam.Value = "Hello world."
     stmt.Execute 'no errors
End Sub ' }
```

Comment: With that approach, I get an *invalid argument* error  when calling `stmt.execute`.

Comment: That's odd. Using the table definition provided by you and the query with a modified parameter name, it works for me. Have you provided a distinctive parameter name (so not ID because that's a column name already)?

Comment: I have update my question with a (non-) working Piece of code that uses a `longbinary` parameter.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger That has an entirely different issue with the `VARCHAR` parameter. Remove that from your code and it runs fine.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Btw, the second error is again a data type definition error. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/sql-data-types), you should use `CHAR` not `VARCHAR`. While synonyms work in some places, they tend to behave finicky.

Comment: I get the same error when using `char(60)` (or `char`, for that matter). However, if I remove everthing that is related to `id` in my example (the table then effectively only consists of the column `txt`), the example works fine. I take this as an indication that something with the guid is behaving differently in my environment than in yours.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Access is a bit weird with data types. See the current edit.

Comment: Indeed, with `binary` it now works on my Installation as well. Thank you  for your patience.