# MS Access with MySQL using DAO Connection Parameter Query Error

Tags: mysql, ms-access

So I'm trying to parameterize my forms as suggested by Parfait. This because my forms are saving on exit and to protect them from a SQL injection. So far I have this code in the on click event of my save button:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim SQL As String

    Set db = OpenDatabase("", False, False, Globales.ConnString)

    SQL = "PARAMETERS nf_param VARCHAR(255), f_param DATETIME, l_param INT(11), s_param INT(11), fd_param VARCHAR(255), sf_param DOUBLE, eie_param DOUBLE, " _
        & "im_param DOUBLE, ie_param DOUBLE, csaie_param DOUBLE, csaim_param DOUBLE, t_param DOUBLE, cs_param DOUBLE, cim_param DOUBLE, cie_param DOUBLE, " _
        & "mp_param VARCHAR(255), imp_param INT(11), pd_param VARCHAR(255);" _
        & " INSERT INTO tbl1facturas (Factura, Fecha, Localidad_ID, Suplidor_ID, Factura_PDF, Subtotal, Exento al IVU Estatal, IVU MUNICIPAL, IVU ESTATAL, CSA IVU ESTATAL, CSA IVU MUNICIPAL, " _
        & "Total de Compra, Credito al Subtotal, Credito IVU Municipal, Credito IVU ESTATAL, Metodo de Pago, ID Metodo Pago, MetodoPago_PDF) " _
        & " VALUES (nf_param, f_param, l_param, s_param, fd_param, sf_param, eie_param, im_param, ie_param, csaie_param, csaim_param, t_param, cs_param, cim_param, cie_param, mp_param, " _
        & "imp_param, pd_param);"

    Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", SQL)

    qdef!nf_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text14
    qdef!f_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text16
    qdef!l_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text18
    qdef!s_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Combo26
    qdef!fd_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text73
    qdef!sf_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text28
    qdef!eie_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text50
    qdef!im_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text42
    qdef!ie_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text46
    qdef!csaie_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text44
    qdef!csaim_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text40
    qdef!t_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text48
    qdef!cs_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text30
    qdef!cim_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text36
    qdef!cie_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text38
    qdef!mp_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text52
    qdef!imp_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text54
    qdef!pd_param = Forms!frmEntradaFacturas!Text75

    qdef.Execute dbFailOnError
    Set qdef = Nothing
```

With this I get the following error when clicking the button:

Run-time error '3139':

Syntax error in PARAMETER clause.

I have looked at my Parameter clause but seems ok. Verified all the datatypes are correct as in mysql table. Verified punctuation seems ok. So I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

All help is welcome! Thanks you alL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building an Access query, and so you need to use Access data types, not MySql data types.

Access doesn't have `VARCHAR(255)` or `INT(11)`, but `TEXT` or `INTEGER`.

Here is a list of Access SQL Data Types:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sql-data-types-9188f41d-6c0e-4733-9d20-d08916f50bd2

There are many synonyms like `LONG` or `DOUBLE`.

You can simply create a dummy query in Access, open the parameter window and define some parameters with various data types, then switch to SQL view to see the names.

Comment: Access does support both `INT` and `VARCHAR` as synonyms for `INTEGER` and `CHAR` (and `TEXT(255)` is a synonym of `CHAR(255)`). See the documentation on [equivalent types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/equivalent-ansi-sql-data-types). A contraintuitive thing is that `VARCHAR` in Access is equivalent to `NVARCHAR` in SQL server. However, I've noted incompatibilities when using some synonyms together, as can be noted in the edit history and comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53961227/7296893)

Comment: Thanks for that link, I didn't find it in a quick search. Access doesn't support `INT(11)`, that's probably the main/only reason for the syntax error. @ErikA

Comment: Thank you Erik A and Andre for the responses! I went on and changed INT(11) to DOUBLES and now it passes the PARAMETERS string but is giving me an error on the INSERT INTO string. Run-time error 3134 Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. I'm confident the column names and table names are correct and dont seem to be missing any commas or anything like that.

Comment: Apparently its not a good idea to have column names with spaces so had to use these bad boys `` to enclose those columns and its working now. Thank you guys you're the best!